# How to simulate events in certain time?

Tags: distributions, modeling, simulation, lognormal-distribution, interarrival-time

I am trying to make simulation, and I have some events that happened durring a day. Some times it s for example few events durring half hour for one day, and sometimes we have event, and then few hours nothihg happened, and then other events and so on. My data set collect data in period of 5 months and I am using R Studio for distribution fitting. This time events I transformed in minutes

```
> fit.weibull <- fitdist(x, "weibull")
> summary(fit.weibull)
Fitting of the distribution ' weibull ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
        estimate Std. Error
shape   4.542143 0.04348223
scale 679.305556 2.10832072
Loglikelihood:  -36309.37   AIC:  72622.74   BIC:  72636.03 
Correlation matrix:
          shape     scale
shape 1.0000000 0.3358675
scale 0.3358675 1.0000000

> y <- rweibull(5672, shape = 4.54, scale = 0.043)
> chisq.test(x,y)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x and y
X-squared = 2887048, df = 2886539, p-value = 0.416
```

What I tryed is:

1. with fitdist I fitted data to weibull dist

2.using model parameter I created new vector of data from weibull dist. with parameters

3.use chisq test compared this two datasets and P = 0.41

I know that inter arrival times are times between events (in my case minimum time between events is 1 minutes, and maximum time is 400 minutes). Should I try to model interarrival time no matter if this events are rare and dispersed durring a day, or mybee to try find (somehow) disttribution of event times.

I analysed times when events occur, and result is shown at the picture below.

[image]

I am observing this data "per day" basis.

Any idea or advice is wellcome, thank you

EDITED:

1. I read that when I validate continious variable KS test is more appropriate since chi square is for discrete variables?

I shifted data, using

```
A <- (x - 400)
```

then remove all data lower then 0 , (only 3 values - extreme) where removed

```
x2 <- A[!A %in% -500:0]
```

then I decided to fit to lognormal

```
> f1<-fitdistr(x2, "lognormal")
> f1
    meanlog       sdlog   
  4.34742821   0.64709906 
 (0.02859801) (0.02022185)
> summary(f1)
         Length Class  Mode   
estimate 2      -none- numeric
sd       2      -none- numeric
vcov     4      -none- numeric
n        1      -none- numeric
loglik   1      -none- numeric
```

and gamma

```
f2<-fitdistr(x2,"Gamma")

hist(x2,col="gray", breaks = 24, freq = FALSE)

with(as.list(coef(f1)),
      curve(dlnorm(x,meanlog,sdlog),
            add=TRUE,col="red",lwd=2))
with(as.list(coef(f2)),
      curve(dgamma(x,shape=shape,rate=rate),
            add=TRUE,col="blue",lwd=2))
```

and for weibull (since this is my first guess)

```
with(as.list(coef(f3)),
       curve(dweibull(x,shape=shape,scale = scale),
            add=TRUE,col="black",lwd=2))
>
```

this produce graph
[image]

As we can see best fit is lognormal. I generated dataset using fited parameters

```
trlnomrG <- rlnorm(512, meanlog = f1$estimate['meanlog'], 
sdlog = f1$estimate['sdlog'])
hist(trlnomrG, breaks = 24, freq = FALSE)
```

and graph is

[image]

And at the end KS test.

```
> ks.test(x2, trlnomrG)

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x2 and trlnomrG
D = 0.089844, p-value = 0.03208
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

and comparing this two dataset using T test

```
> t.test(x2, trlnomrG)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x2 and trlnomrG
t = 0.45766, df = 990.82, p-value = 0.6473
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.840123 11.000993
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 97.00391  94.92347
```

So my final question is can I use lognormal distribution to generate those times, thx?

Comment: What do you mean by “can I use [the] lognormal distribution to generate [interarrival] times”? If you mean “is it possible?”, then the answer is yes because you’ve already done it. If you mean “is it advisable?”, then an answer would depend on what you would do with this model.

Comment: I am trying to make simulation of sending emails (this is usualy modeled using poisson and interarrival times that follow exponentials distribution but this is not appropriate for my data - events per time period is not constant ) so I choose this approach ( I read somewhare that in case like this (rare events) it s possible to model arrival times so I choose this approach. According to my P value can I use the lognormal distribution for modeling arrival times?

Comment: 1) I would try modeling those Emil’s with a process and not just a distribution, eg with lognormal arrival times whose log-means follow a Brownian motion. 2) The question “according to my P value” does not indicate what would be tested. I will not comment further.